# XMPP IOS Openfire disconnected after sending element

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

after sending custom element i get disconnected.Is there a way? my code for connection

```
  [self addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[self setHostName:@"bowerchat.com"];
[self setHostPort:5222];

self.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@bowerchat.com",UD_getObj(@"myPhoneNumber")]];

NSError * error;
[self connectWithTimeout:300 error:&error];
```

disconnected issue

```
Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer"
```

After found problem i changed @"type" parameter as @"type2" and it is working now...but i cannot find why?

```
-(void)sendMessageToServer:(NSDictionary*)paraDict{
NSString * userPhone = [[DBHelper sharedObject]getUserPhone:paraDict[@"friend_id"]];
NSXMLElement *a = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"request" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];
if(paraDict[@"type"] != nil){
NSMutableDictionary * k = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:paraDict];

    NSString * typeValue = [k[@"type"]copy];
    [k removeObjectForKey:@"type"];
    [k setObject:typeValue forKey:@"type2"];

paraDict = k;
}
XMPPElement *e = [[XMPPElement alloc] initWithName:@"message"];
for(NSString * key in paraDict.allKeys){
    [e addAttributeWithName:key stringValue:paraDict[key]];
}
[e addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:getJabberString(userPhone)];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:getMyJabberString];
[e addChild:a];
NSLog(@"%@",[e attributesAsDictionary]);
[self sendElement:e];
```

}

Comment: You are not showing any custom element in this code. You are not even showing anything relating to server or connection, just formatting a JID. Could you please expand / clarify your question ?

Comment: i found problem.the problem is attirube name of type.if there is attribute name "type" the error occurs.why?

Comment: Please, update your question to show the XMPP packet causing issue. This is needed to get a meaningful reply.

Comment: updated.@MickaëlRémond

Answer (score 2):

The message type attribute is build into the XMPP protocol. It has a precise meaning on XMPP and you cannot put what you want as the value of the type message attribute. As defined in XMPP RFC, the only possible types are:

- chat
- error
- groupchat
- headline
- normal

You cannot put anything in message type, or indeed, otherwise the server should disconnect you.

Reference: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-syntax-type

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/XMPP_IM_Client_Design_Guidelines#When_making_a_custom_extension.2C_add_new_elements_to_.3Cmessage.3E.2C_.3Ciq.3E_or_.3Cpresence.3E_stanzas)'s a good guideline on how to add custom data to your stanzas:

> Do **not**:
>
> - Add new attributes on the `<message>`, `<iq>` or `<presence>` elements.
> - Create new type values for stanzas.
> - Create new top-level elements.
> - Put your custom data in the `<body>` of a `<message>`.
> - Invent new values for the `<show>` element in `<presence>` stanzas (allowed values are listed in [RFC 6121 section 4.7.2.1](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-syntax-children-show))
>
> Do:
>
> Add a new XML element in your own namespace:
>
> ```
> <message
>    from='romeo@montague.net/orchard'
>    to='juliet@capulet.com/balcony'
>    type='chat'>
>    <data xmlns='https://example.im/my-awesome-new-xmpp-app'></data>
> </message>
> ```